# Angular 7 - not triggering "valueChanges" from the template (using mat-option)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form control. In my template I am changing it using mat-option, but I want that this specific change will not trigger valueChanges (I have other changes that I want that "valueChanges" will be called).

My component-

```
inputControl = new FormControl('');


    ngOnInit() {
        this.inputControl.valueChanges
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy))
            .subscribe(val => {
              //do something
            });
    }
```

html-

```
<ng-container *ngIf="inputControl.value as val">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let result of autocompleteResults; let i = index" [value]="result.displayName"
                    (onSelectionChange)="searchByResult($event, result)">
           {{result.displayName}}
        </mat-option>
    </ng-container>
```

Any idea if this is possible somehow?

Comment: selectionChange event should be on mat-select , not on mat-option; ;;;;;;;;;;
                 Ex: <mat-select (selectionChange)="searchByResult($event, result)">

Answer (score 0):

Your mat-option must be wrapped inside of mat-select as below

```
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

Checkout the documentation of angular material. It has pretty good examples with code snippets

Heres the link:
https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview